# Ajax form not submitting and updating a partialview

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm going crazy on this... I've been trying to figure out how to use ajax to update a partial view for quite some time...  I've got to be missing something simple and easy.

I'm in VS2012, MVC4.

First, I do have these bundles loaded:

```
@Styles.Render("~/css") 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/js" ) 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

I have also tried to specify the unobtrusive script manually as well...

Then I have this in my view:

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index_AddGroup", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AddGroupList" }))
        { 
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.NewGroups.GroupName)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.AllGroups.nSelectGroupID, Model.AllGroups.GroupList, "Select Group to Add")
                <input type="submit" value="Add Group" /> 
            </div>
        }
```

Then I load a partial view:

```
            <div id="AddGroupList">
            @if(Model.Groups != null)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_AddGroups", Model.Groups);
            }
        </div>
```

In that partial view I do the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.ViewModels.Group>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Added Groups";
}

<h2>Groups to be Added</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Group Name</th>
        <th>Added until</th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.GroupName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.EndDate)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index_AddGroup(SearchedUser viewModel)
    {
        AddGroupsContext db = new AddGroupsContext();

        Group NewGroup = new Group();
        NewGroup.GroupName = "test";//viewModel.

        db.Groups.Add(NewGroup);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("_AddGroups", db.Groups);
    }
```

I loaded up fiddler and clicked on the button but no request was being sent.  Why isn't that javascript/ajax code running?

Comment: I was playing around with this and discovered something interesting...  I copied the form to another page on my app and I could see that it was trying to hit the controller.  I had to remove the two model objects because the model didn't exist on the page.  I went back to the page that had the form and if I remove the drop down box and leave the label for, the form submits.  What is going on with that?

Comment: More over, I can add an editorfor and the form works (as long as the dropdown control is not there).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a submit button. try:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Group" />
```

Also i think you will need to add a reference to as it doesn't look like it is included anywhere:

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

I think you can get it through nuget if you dont have it already.

otherwise here is a script tag that includes a CDN link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too.  I did try that a few minutes ago with the same results.. =/

Comment: is the Index_AddGroup Action on the same controller that the page is served from? your not seeing anything in fiddler?

Comment: Correct.  Its in the same controller.  I also have a breakpoint set in that function but when it wasn't stopping I loaded up fiddler to watch what was going on.  Nothing happens in fiddler when I click on the submit button.

Comment: I just added the controller above.  However, I would have thought that if the controller wasn't found, I'd get an exception...?  I tried to change the name of the action in the view to see if I could get an exception and nothing happened.

Comment: yeah your right.  if your not seeing it in fiddler it is not leaving the browser.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your code as it looks right now and add the code for Index_AddGroup as well?